# Proof attempt for a weaker form of the Collatz Conjecture

Tags: solution-verification, collatz-conjecture

I am kind of new to this problem and I tried solving it with open mind. Please don't be judgmental, this is what I got.

Let us assume, for the sake of contradiction, that the Collatz conjecture is false and that there exists a cycle in the Collatz sequence other than the well-known $4-2-1$ loop. Consider this hypothetical cycle, which must have a minimum and a maximum points.

We focus our attention solely on the orbit from the minimum point to the maximum point. We define a local minimum point as a point that once we reach it in the orbit the value cannot decrease any further as we continue along the orbit. It is important to note three facts about these local minimum points:

1.In Collatz sequence generated between any two numbers f and g, f<g there exist at least one local minimum point. If there is no such local minimum point then f itself serves as local minimum.

2. Local minimum points must be odd, as even numbers would decrease upon division by $2$, contradicting the definition of a local minimum.
3. Between two consecutive local minimum points, there can be no numbers in their sequence that connect them, as any such point would also create a local minimum (*according to 1) , thus violating its definition.

Let us consider a local minimum point $r$. Since $r$ is odd, multiplying it by $3$ and adding $1$ yields an even number. Dividing this even number by $2$ gives us $1.5r+0.5$. Therefore, the next local minimum point must lie somewhere in the range between $r+1$ and $1.5r+0.5$, inclusive. If no such point exists in this range, it contradicts our assumption, as it would indicate a decrease below the minimum of the local minimum.

The only exception to this rule is the last local minimum point before reaching the maximum point. For simplification let us denote the maximum point as $9p+1$, and the last local minimum point as $3p$ (were $p$ belongs to Real as no numbers in the sequence divide by 3), which has an orbit length of $1$ and rises.

Now, let us examine the second highest local minimum point in the orbit, denoted as $2p+a$, where $a$ is an integer lower than $p$. Following the path from this local minimum, applying the transformations of $3n+1$ and division by $2$, we arrive at the expression $3p +1.5a +0.5$.

Considering both possibilities, if the resulting number is odd, it exceeds the maximum number. Therefore, it must be even so we dividing by $2$ getting $1.5p+0.75a+0.25$. However, comparing the inequality $1.5p+0.75a+0.25 < 3p$ to the fact that $a < p$, we find that a point exists between two local minimums, contradicting our assumption of the existence of a cycle other than the $4-2-1$ loop.

It still not proving that there no sequence that goes to infinity though

Please tell me what you think about it.

Comment: If the Collatz conjecture is false, is it really true that there is a cycle that avoids $1$? *A priori* it is reasonable to suppose that we get a non-periodic sequence of iterates (EDIT: I see you touch on this at the end)

Comment: But do i have flaws on the proof that there arent any cycles accept 4-2-1?

Comment: <quote>Between two consecutive local minimum points, there can be no numbers in their orbit that connect them, as any such point would also be a local minimum and eventually reach the higher local minimum of the two, thus violating its definition.</quote>

This made very little sense to me.  "Connect", "orbit", and "reach" do not have clear meanings I can discern from context.

Comment: Im sorry ill try to clarify , By "orbit," I am referring to the sequence of numbers that are generated by applying the Collatz function repeatedly to a given starting number.  And by saying “orbit that connect” I mean only the numbers that are generated by applying the Collatz until you get a desired number

Comment: Even that $4-2-1$ is the only loop is just a conjecture and apparently completely out of reach to be proven with the current known methods. Of course , the possibility of divergent trajectories can neither be ruled out , but even the weak version is still open.

Comment: What do you mean by 3p ? there is no multiple of 3 in a cycle.

Comment: indeed there is no multiplication of 3 in cycle, I edit my post to clarify more . I just denoted 3p for simple math.

Comment: It does not make much more sense to me but anyway. First, I don't see how you can tell something about a global behavior (cycle) by looking locally.  Second, it looks like you are saying that a maximum in (any) sequence is impossible because it would contradict something, and that does not make much sense either. But I must admit I didn't dig much deeper since I don't even understand how you came to your conclusion

Comment: I am sorry I wasnt clear enough as I am a rookie.
why cant I negatively assume  there is other cycle other than 4-2-1 and it has a maximum and minimum points such as the loop 4-2-1 that 1 is a minimum point and 4 is a maximum point and you cant exceed those points as you continue generate the sequence ?

Comment: You can assume another cycle, but the contradiction must be the result of your assumption. Here you look locally at the maximum of your sequence, and all sequences (not just cycles) have a maximum (unless it is a divergent sequence). My second point is that you found a contradiction in that region which would imply that no sequence can have a maximum, even all known sequences reaching 1.

Comment: my guess is that your point 3 is at fault. You can have a local minimum connected to another local minimum by an even number (local minimum = $n$, second local minimum = $\frac{3n+1}{4}$ connected by $\frac{3n+1}{2}$), the even number being larger then both local minimums. But I might have misinterpreted your "local minimum" which is not clear since it is hard for $n$ to be a local minimum if it is one step before the absolute maximum

Comment: I think you understand  what I meant and I see your point, as I didnt took care of that scenario at the end that the 2 local minimums connected by one even number.
thanks for the reply

Comment: When trying to understand cycles for 3x+1, it can be useful to apply one's logic to generalizations such as mx+a where m and a are odd integers. For example, 3x+5 and 5x+1 each have multiple cycles. What does your logic say about these?

Comment: Why can you denote the second highest local minimum as 2p+a? Since p is not an integer (as I understood) and 3p is, wouldn't that mean that 2p cannot be an integer?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it can help you with your reasoning but I had started building the following graph that represents odd numbers of the sequence with some jumps so that you can have a cyclical representation.

As you can see for each line are represented in the circles the different residue classes of $n \pmod {2^c}$, with increasing exponent $c$.

I have not completed the graph because probably, even if for each branch it is possible to find an increasing pattern, it is impossible to complete it since there will always be a new residue class that does not follow the previous pattern.

However, as you can see, apart from the number $n=1$ followed by $1$ in a cyclical manner, all the other numbers have a smaller number as their next number, therefore the local minimum decreases. In any case, this proves nothing because it is not said that the graph can be completed.
[image]